# Android search listview like dial pad search(search for both name and number)

Tags: android

I created a dial pad by using grid view and i got my call log in list view, i enabled search functionality to call log  with user entered number(from gridview). Now how can i search my call log with contact name also. suppose when user entered 7 it is showing call log containing 7 number, its not showing call log containing letters p,q,r,s  in the contact name. I have to filter both same time.

DialerHomeActivity.java

```
callListAdapter=new CustomAdapter(DialerHomeActivity.this, R.layout.list_row, Common.calloglist);

   /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    // Capture Text in EditText
    phone_num_edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text = phone_num_edt.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            callListAdapter.filter(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CallData> implements Filterable{

 //String _heading, _comm;
 private Activity activity;
 private List<CallData> listdata=null;
 private LayoutInflater mInflater=null;
 private ArrayList<CallData> arraylist;
 private CallData objBean;
 private int listRow;

 public CustomAdapter(Activity context, int listRow, List<CallData> calldata) {
  super(context, listRow, calldata);

  this.listdata=calldata;
  this.listRow = listRow;
  this.activity = context;
  mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  this.arraylist = new ArrayList<CallData>();
  this.arraylist.addAll(listdata);

 }

public void filter(String charText) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    listdata.clear();
   if (charText.length() == 0) {

    listdata.addAll(arraylist);

   }else {

       for (CallData ob : arraylist) {

           if (ob.getCallnumber().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)){

            listdata.add(ob);
           }
       }
   }

   notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
 public int getCount() {
  return listdata.size();
 }


 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  final ViewHolder holder;

  if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
   holder = new ViewHolder();
   convertView = mInflater.inflate(listRow, null);

   holder.calltype = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.call_logo_imageView);
   holder.callnumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.callNumber_tv);            
   holder.calldate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.callDate_tv);
  // holder.callduration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.callDuration_tv);
   //holder.heading = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heading_tv);
   //holder.addImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add_comment_imageView);
   holder.contactOptions_rl = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.options_rv);
   holder.numRelLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number_rl);
   holder.optionsImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_imageView);
         convertView.setTag(holder);
  }
  else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }

  CallData calldatalist=listdata.get(position);

  final String callnumber = calldatalist.getCallnumber();
  final String contactname = calldatalist.getContactName();
  String calltype = calldatalist.getCalltype();
  String calldate = calldatalist.getCalldatetime(); 
  final String contact_call_id = calldatalist.getCall_ID();
  //String callduration=calldatalist.getCallduration();

  if(calltype == "INCOMING") {
      holder.calltype.setImageResource(R.drawable.incoming);
  }if(calltype == "OUTGOING") {
      holder.calltype.setImageResource(R.drawable.outgoing);
  }if(calltype == "MISSED") {
      holder.calltype.setImageResource(R.drawable.missed);
  }

  if(null != contactname) {
      holder.callnumber.setText(contactname);
  }else {
      holder.callnumber.setText(callnumber);
  }
 // holder.calltype.setText(calltype);
  holder.calldate.setText(String.valueOf(calldate));
  //holder.callduration.setText(callduration+" sec");



  notifyDataSetChanged();
  return convertView;

 }

}

class ViewHolder {

   public ImageView optionsImage;
   public TextView callnumber, calldate, callduration, heading;
   public ImageView calltype, nextImage;
   public RelativeLayout contactOptions_rl, numRelLayout;
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: add name filtering inside: for (CallData ob : arraylist) {

Comment: ok, i am getting only numbers from activity, how can i get alphabets along with number

Comment: you already  answered that  question by yourself,  if the user presses 7 search for p or q or r or s

Comment: I think its not the correct way to do, @satya's answer will give better solution.

Comment: Hi @pskink i tried something like this   if (ob.getCallnumber().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)
                     ||ob.getContactName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains("p") 
                  || ob.getContactName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains("q")
                  || ob.getContactName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains("r")
                  || ob.getContactName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains("s")){
                 
                 listdata.add(ob);
          } but i got null pointer exception at .contains("p") condetion

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use pattern matching algorithm for this.

Comment: Yes @Satya, can you provide regular expression pattern matching code for this.